# matlab code for golden ratio continued fraction

Tags: matlab, loops, fractions, continued-fractions

I'm trying to write a Matlab function that computes how many terms, m, it takes the golden fraction to get to n digits of accuracy. Here is what I have so far, but I keep getting an output of 0.

```
phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
p=1;
p=[1+1/p];
LoopCounter = 0;
while (phi-p)>10^(-n)
    p=[1+1/p];
    LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1;
end
m=LoopCounter;
m
```

I think this is a common question for those studying Number Theory or just starting to learn Matlab. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` condition is missing an `abs`. It should be

```
while abs(phi-p)>10^(-n)
```

With your code as it stands, the initial value of `p` (namely 2) is greater than `phi`, so `phi-p` is negative and the `while` loop is never entered. That's why you get `m` equal to `0`.

Comment: Also, note the brackets in `p=[1+1/p]` are not necessary